# Java sort ascending in international delivery list according to delivery id

Tags: java, arraylist

This is coding in class app in java. This class app about delivery in local and oversea. So, I need to sorted the oversea id number ascending.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
public class Delivery App
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList myDeliveryList = new ArrayList();

    Delivery d;
    d = new Delivery("Hassan Ali", "R4321", 'L', 93.59);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Ahmad Kassim", "M1131", 'O', 11.56);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Atikah Hussin", "S4321", 'L', 81.24);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Umi Rina", "P9087", 'L', 27.98);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Lam Ah Soon", "R2342", 'O', 25.67);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Zaidi Zain", "N8876", 'O', 51.99);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Mohd. Mahmud", "D3321", 'L', 13.32);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Gopal Samy", "S1134", 'L', 80.87);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Ina Naim", "P3456", 'O', 32.67);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);
    d = new Delivery("Suffian Suhaimi", "P3217", 'L', 79.88);
    myDeliveryList.add(d);

    for(int i=0; i<myDeliveryList.size(); i++)
    {
       d= (Delivery)myDeliveryList.get(i);
       //to display detail about hassan ali only
       if (d.getCN().equalsIgnoreCase("hassan ali"))
       {
          System.out.println(d.toString());
       }
    }


    //to make a new ArrayList for local and oversea
    ArrayList LocalDeliveryList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList InternationalDeliveryList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0; i<myDeliveryList.size(); i++)
    {
      d= (Delivery)myDeliveryList.get(i);
      //to add all destination in their own categorize
      if (d.getD() == 'L')
      {
          LocalDeliveryList.add(d);
      }
      else
      {
          InternationalDeliveryList.add(d);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("\nPackage delivered to local destination : "+LocalDeliveryList.size());
    System.out.println(" Package delivered to international destination: "+InternationalDeliveryList.size());


    double Ltotal=0.00;
    double Ototal=0.00;
    double priceL;
    double priceO;
    //to calculate the total for one package either in local and oversea
    for (int i=0; i<myDeliveryList.size(); i++)
    {
      d= (Delivery)myDeliveryList.get(i);
      if (d.getD() == 'L')
      {
          priceL = 7.00;
          Ltotal = priceL*d.getW();
      }
      else
      {
          priceO = 11.00;
          Ototal = priceO*d.getW();
      }
    }
```

I try to sort it using `collections.sort()` but it can't be read. Can you guys help me to sort the international delivery by id numbers. I just want to sort the id number in international delivery list.

Comment: Don't use raw types: `ArrayList<Delivery> myDeliveryList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: its in on my question and i only rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
InternationalDeliveryList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Delivery::getId));
```

`getId` -  is the getter method of the field on which you want to sort

Also specify the types while creating the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Delivery> InternationalDeliveryList = new ArrayList();
```

Entire code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;import java.util.Comparator;

public class Delivery {
    private String cN;
    private char d;
    private double w;
    private String number;

    Delivery(String cN,String number,char d,double w){
        this.cN=cN;
        this.number=number;
        this.d=d;
        this.w=w;
    }

    public double getW() {
        return w;
    }

    public void setW(double w) {
        this.w = w;
    }

    public char getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(char d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getCN() {
        return cN;
    }

    public void setCN(String cN) {
        this.cN = cN;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Delivery> myDeliveryList = new ArrayList();

        Delivery d;
        d = new Delivery("Hassan Ali", "R4321", 'L', 93.59);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Ahmad Kassim", "M1131", 'O', 11.56);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Atikah Hussin", "S4321", 'L', 81.24);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Umi Rina", "P9087", 'L', 27.98);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Lam Ah Soon", "R2342", 'O', 25.67);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Zaidi Zain", "N8876", 'O', 51.99);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Mohd. Mahmud", "D3321", 'L', 13.32);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Gopal Samy", "S1134", 'L', 80.87);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Ina Naim", "P3456", 'O', 32.67);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);
        d = new Delivery("Suffian Suhaimi", "P3217", 'L', 79.88);
        myDeliveryList.add(d);

        for (int i = 0; i < myDeliveryList.size(); i++) {
            d = (Delivery) myDeliveryList.get(i);
            // to display detail about hassan ali only
            if (d.getCN().equalsIgnoreCase("hassan ali")) {
                System.out.println(d.toString());
            }
        }

        // to make a new ArrayList for local and oversea
        ArrayList LocalDeliveryList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Delivery> InternationalDeliveryList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < myDeliveryList.size(); i++) {
            d = (Delivery) myDeliveryList.get(i);
            // to add all destination in their own categorize
            if (d.getD() == 'L') {
                LocalDeliveryList.add(d);
            } else {
                InternationalDeliveryList.add(d);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nPackage delivered to local destination : " + LocalDeliveryList.size());
        System.out.println(" Package delivered to international destination: " + InternationalDeliveryList.size());

        InternationalDeliveryList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Delivery::getW));

        for(Delivery delivery: InternationalDeliveryList) {
            System.out.println(delivery.getW());
        }

        double Ltotal = 0.00;
        double Ototal = 0.00;
        double priceL;
        double priceO;
        // to calculate the total for one package either in local and oversea
        for (int i = 0; i < myDeliveryList.size(); i++) {
            d = (Delivery) myDeliveryList.get(i);
            if (d.getD() == 'L') {
                priceL = 7.00;
                Ltotal = priceL * d.getW();
            } else {
                priceO = 11.00;
                Ototal = priceO * d.getW();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment (otherwise I would have), but make sure `Collections.sort()` is capitalized when you try to use it.

You could also convert your ArrayList to an array by using `Object[] deliveryListArray = myDeliveryList.toArray(new Object[10]);` (you can change `deliveryListArray` to whatever you want to name the array) and then utilizing `Arrays.sort()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

*You could use streams*

define this method in the `Delivery` class:

```
static public int compare( Object delivery1, Object delivery2 ) {
  return( ((Delivery)delivery1).getID().compareTo( ((Delivery)delivery2).getID() ) );
}
```

and sort the list with something like that:

```
List<Delivery> sorted = 
    (List<Delivery>)internationalDeliveryList.stream().sorted( Delivery::compare ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

better to add the typedef to the `internationalDeliveryList` to avoid the `(List<Delivery>)` cast

Comment: Thank you so much... I really appreciate it... and its working...